# Express session issue with multiple routes is undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express-session

I am using this library for creating new shopify app in reactjs. https://github.com/fullstackreact/food-lookup-demo

But when I am trying to use session its not working with multiple routes for example:

```
req.session.shop = 'yshop'; set in shopify file and when I am trying to get 
console.log(req.session.shop); in another routes file its showing undefined.
```

server.js code:

```
app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
app.use(session({
  secret: "fd34s@!@dfa453f3DF#$D&W",
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  proxy: true,
  cookie: { secure: true, maxAge: 60000 }
}));
```

Its not working, anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to set a session name like this :

```
app.use(session({
  secret: "fd34s@!@dfa453f3DF#$D&W",
  name: 'mySessionName',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  proxy: true,
  cookie: { secure: true, maxAge: 60000 }
}));
```

I'm not sure it will doing the trick, but I'm also setting `saveUninitialized:false` on my configuration.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok let me try this.

Comment: No its not working, still showing undefined in console.log